# Web API 2 - Authorize authenticated mobile users

Tags: azure, xamarin.forms, asp.net-web-api2, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to secure my Web API 2 with the classic [Autorize] attribute on my controllers. This is successful, now I don't have access to my API ! Great !

I have a Xamarin application, from which I consume the REST services of the app and on which I have a Microsoft Graph Identity provider implemented.

So once I'm logged in the app via Microsoft Graph, I would like to consume the API.

Can anyone point me to the right documentation to do so or explain to me how I should proceed?

I'm guessing there is a way to user the user token provided by the microsoft graph API but I can't see how.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT : 
Adding some code from the API after being asked to :

the Startup.Auth.cs :

```
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
        app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
            new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Audience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Audience"],
                Tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"]
            });
        }
```

From the Xamarin app, I log in like this :

```
        public async Task Signin()
        {
        try
        {
            if (App.IdentityClientApp != null)
            {
                var authenticationResult = await App.IdentityClientApp.AcquireTokenAsync(App.ClientScope);
                this.UserToken = result.Token;
                this.expiration = result.ExpiresOn;
            }
            else
                Debug.WriteLine("Identity client is null");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Technically I should provide the token as an AuthenticationHeaderValue with the "Bearer" key. 
But I'm not sure that is the right way to go.

Comment: Please share the code where you have added authentication settings to your Web API application. If you haven't already done so, you should take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devquickstarts-webapi-dotnet.

Comment: Hi thanks for your anwer. My code is pretty much the exact same thing as the documentation.
I'll edit my question.